# Boostrap. Navbar issue, dont stick at top

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, fullpage.js

I'm working with a "one-page template" from scratch (just for fun and learn).
I started checking the examples from [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/). Later, I noticed that my div's does not fill width/height as I wanted, so I decided to try to work this out with simple CCS but failed, then, in another example, I used some code from FullPage.js.

I really like this bootstrap example and my only purpose is to fill every div on screen but keeping the nav at the top.

I have two working examples on jsfiddle to let you know what I'm doing.

1: [fullpaje.js](http://jsfiddle.net/willyxvkei/pmb5dg0k/6/): In this, the navbar doesn't work properly when fullscreen but it does when is not fullscreen, yeah weird.. I mean, with a fullscreen doesn't show in what div are you checking, on another hand when isn't fullscreen it works. (maybe in jsfiddle works because is not fs, try to put the code and save it in an HTML file to see what I'm saying)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        /* no options */
        });
    });
```

2: [just with css](http://jsfiddle.net/willyxvkei/pmb5dg0k/): In this, the navbar get lost in the second div and I don't know if it works correctly. It just disappears while scrolling down.

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#section1 { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#section2 { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#section3 { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#section4 { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Do you have any suggestion about this?
Thanks

Comment: @MiXT4PE In the most kind and attentive way, I invite you to say that if you are not going to help, do not comment. My question is well formulated, if not theres an "edit button" where you can change what you dont like. Thank you.

Comment: It is always a good idea to follow StackOverflow's suggestions on how to post. They're not just guidelines, they'll help you get better responses. 
As for your question, the first example works for me on jsfiddle, and the second doesn't have a navbar at all (not in the HTML anyway).

Comment: Also, is Bootstrap a requirement in your question? You're not calling it in either one of your fiddles...

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz I paste an inccorrect link from the example. Sorry ,my bad.

Comment: I didnt paste all code, because theres the main topic in each one. the jquery function of fullpage.js in one, only css in the other example.
Both examples are the same bootstraped template.

Answer (score 0):

I put the HTML code in a file and ran it & saw the same issue. The way i fixed it was downloading the jquery.easings / scrolloverflow JavaScript packages and jquery.fullPage Style sheet page, do you have these installed?

Comment: Hi, i do have those files . I checked the console and theres no error. When i check it in Chrome (full screen) the selector on navbar dont change their color. I noticed it change when the resolution is under 900px width

Comment: The classes change their name when i change the resolution. I think thats the main problem hehe , both js fles  conflict each other